# How to check if item (LxWxH) fits in box (LxWxH)?

Tags: php, algorithm

What would be the easiest way to check if an item of L x W x H fits in a box of L x W x H?

The algorithm would need to allow for rotations of the item.

Comment: Is it an object? does it have properties? Is it a string? An array?

Comment: This is called the bin packing problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem You will get quite a few algorithms online

Comment: Several bin packing apis out there... Check out **[this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192087/3-dimensional-bin-packing-algorithms)**

Comment: This is just one item in one box. Does it still apply? Is there no easy method?

Comment: Just sort the sides `L1>W1>H1`(item), `L2>W2>H2`(box) and check if `L1<L2 and W1<W2 and H1<H2`