# Bin packing in csharp

Tags: c#, bin-packing, choco

I need to minimize number of trucks to be loaded by packages. It is less then 50 packages. They are loaded in row.
I can solve this problem using choco-solver written in java, but I need to call it from c#. Do you have any idea how to easily do it? Is there some library for c#, which can solve this problem? I need to find perfect solution, or at least very optimized.

Comment: I'm sure your project has more parameters than simply loading 50 packages into an unknown number of trucks. What code have you tried, and what do you need to solve?

Comment: I have to load packages ranges from 2-10 meters into about 14 meters long truck. Customer chooses packages in eshop and I have to tell him how many trucks he will need.

Comment: Would it be an option to use a heuristic or an approximation algorithm? There seem to be only 9 different sizes of packages. Perhaps [FFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#First-fit_algorithm) is an option.

Comment: @ jan please have a look          http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/706136/Csharp-Bin-Packing-Cutting-Stock-Solver

Comment: thank you, it is not bad, but I need a little better solution. We used something similar until now [link](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem/Bounded#JavaScript), but we have many bad feedbacks, so we are searching for something little more accurate.

Comment: @janhruska see my repo https://github.com/cariquitanmac/2D-Bin-Pack-Binary-Search you can leverage from here

Answer (score -1):

What about setting up the choco solver model on a java server that would be called from C# (or whatever) via a webservices (using JSON to exchange i/o data for instance)? It is clean and easy. [We](https://www.cosling.com/) can do it very quickly if you like.

Answer (score -1):

Since the only answer doesn't suggest anything - here's two SO threads that discuss the same problem.

[3 dimensional bin packing algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192087/3-dimensional-bin-packing-algorithms)

[3d bin packing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563271/3d-bin-packing-algorithm)

I've found these two C# repos that seems promising:

https://github.com/davidmchapman/3DContainerPacking

https://github.com/303248153/Sharp3DBinPacking